# Natron Animation rendering

Tags: animation

I can't figure out the problem, What is the warning really mean? After rendering my animated video, I found no video file in my document.

Here is the picture of the problem I found.

[Photo.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj820.png)

While writing, I found the problem.
[Photo.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SWzK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use Write node.

Select *Write Node* from *Image->Write*, choose proper destination and frame count and press F7.

**File path** means, where you want to save and ### means 3-digit frame number. For example, file path should be like this: `/path/to/desired/output/directory/###.jpg`

**Frame range** means, how many frames should be rendered. You can press <kbd>S</kbd> and give desired frame range from *Frame range: last* field.